# What is the difference between "I'll go to the sea." and "I will be going to the sea."

Tags: differences

What is the difference between 
"I'll go to the sea."
and 
"I will be going to the sea."

If it's ok with you, could you tell me how to use these?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! What is the context and usage? Can you provide examples of each?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference except for one thing:

***"I will be going to the sea"*** shows the possibility of going, while ***"I'll go to the sea"*** is confirmative.

Answer (score 0):

"I'll go to the sea" majorly states your wish whereas "I'll be going to the sea" states the possibility of happening in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go to sea = shows an intention to do something.

Another example: I'll open the window when the room becomes too warm. (intention)

I'll be going to sea = means you will definitely be going at some point.

Another example: I'll be going home when we finish this work. (future action will definitely occur after the work is finished). In your example, /I'll be going/ implies some other action takes place before it (which you have not stated).

The future continuous is used to show an ongoing action in the future after the occurrence of another action.
Since the action is ongoing in the future, it is normally (but not always) used to contrast with another action that will occur at some specific point in the future.

I'll be working in Hong Kong after my son finishes secondary school.

VERSUS:
I was working in Hong Kong after my son finished secondary school.

VERSUS:
I'm working in Hong Kong while my son finishes or is finishing secondary school.

Please note: to sea, meaning: to sail on the ocean, to be aboard a sea-going vessel, to work on a sea-going vessel

If you mean going to beach, we'd say: go to the seashore, go to beach, go to the shore (AmE), and probably others.